# C# shortcut notation to create class instance

Tags: c#, constructor, shortcut, instantiation

I'm sure there was a way to easily create an instance of a class but my search of the great interwebs hasn't found it.  Lets say I have this:

```
List<LicencedCustomer> leftList = new List<LicencedCustomer>();

leftList.Add(new LicencedCustomer (LMAA_CODE:"1",LICENSE_NUMBER:"1",TRADING_NAME:"Bobs Liquor",STATE:"NSW",POSTCODE:"2261"));
```

My class looks like the below.

```
public class LicencedCustomer
{

    public string LMAA_CODE {get; set;}
    public string LICENSE_NUMBER {get; set;}
    public string TRADING_NAME {get; set;}
    public string STATE  {get; set;}
    public string POSTCODE  {get; set;}

    public LicencedCustomer(string LMAA_CODE, string LICENSE_NUMBER, string TRADING_NAME, string STATE, string POSTCODE)
    {
        this.LMAA_CODE = LMAA_CODE;
        this.LICENSE_NUMBER = LICENSE_NUMBER;
        this.TRADING_NAME = TRADING_NAME;
        this.STATE = STATE;
        this.POSTCODE = POSTCODE;
    }

    ...
```

Without the constructor immediately above, I get an error that the class doesn't contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments (initially I tried it with the values only and no field names in the List.Add function).

Is there a shortcut that allows assignment to properties on creation, without needing to define the constructor explicitly?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wide ranging curiosity has resulted from the capitalised properties - they are only that way because they've been built to reflect the headings of an import file.  Not my preferred method!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use new ( ) you call a constructor that matches the parameters. If you have no defined constructors you will get an implicit parameter less constructor.

To use the shortcut initializer use something like this.

```
public class sCls
{
    public int A;
    public string B;

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   sCls oCls = new sCls() {A = 4, B = "HI"};
}
```

Edit

---

From comments if you add a consturctor that takes a paramter you lose the implict paramterless constructor

```
public class sCls
{
    public sCls(string setB)
    {
        B = setB;
    }
    public int A;
    public string B;

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sCls oCls = new sCls() {A = 4, B = "HI"}; // ERROR  error CS1729: 'csCA.Program.sCls' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
}
```

You can also use any constructor with the initializer list

```
public class sCls
{
    public sCls(string setB)
    {
        B = setB;
    }
    public int A;
    public string B;

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sCls oCls = new sCls("hi") {A = 4, B = "HI"};
}
```

Remember that in all cases the constructor is called before the initializer list even if it has a parameter less constructor. So base class constructions or anything else that happens in the construction of the object will happen first.

```
    public class BSE
    {
        public BSE()
        {
            BaseA = "Bob";
        }
        public string BaseA;
    }
    public class sCls :BSE
    {

        public int A;
        public string B;

    }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        sCls oCls = new sCls() {A = 4, B = "HI" };
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", oCls.BaseA);//Prints Bob
}
```

Comment: +1 Perhaps also point out that when using the initializer block (??) the ctor parenthesis can be omitted for the argument-less ctor, and that the initializer block can be used with any ctor.

Comment: Hi pst, would you mind explaining a bit more about what you mean here?  Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Add a default constructor, then try something like:

```
new LicencedCustomer() { LMAA_CODE = ..., LICENSE_NUMBER = ..., ... };
```

<sub>Side note: It's not conventional to capitalize properties.</sub>

Comment: It might be convention if they were constants.

Comment: Not even for abbreviations, see `HttpClient`.

Comment: @jocull They have setters, so they aren't constants.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Also not `public const`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments.  The reason those fields are capitalised is because the class was built by a file parsing library, and for consistency I've made each property match the field header in the input file.  In this case the field headers in the file were capitalised.

Comment: When you say 'add a default constructor', should it just set each field to a blank/default or similar?

Comment: @Glinkot auto properties will be initialised to `default(T)` no matter what you do, so whether you set them yourself or not is neither here nor there. A default constructor is just a constructor without any parameters.

Comment: @Glinkot: What @Matthew said. =)

Comment: @jocull: I've never seen capitalized properties of any kind... not sure what you mean by "constant properties" either. :\

Comment: @jocull - see my earlier comment